# Terminology: What is the tuple $(x, x)$ called?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I need to write a few functions in PowerShell which operate on sequences, but I want to use accepted mathematical terminology if possible.

I will be using the following terminology ($S$ and $T$ are sets):

- $S \times T$ is called a Cartesian product. I will call it `Product` in my code.
- $S \times S$ is called the Cartesian square. I will call it `Square` in my code.

When `Square`-ing, sometimes I only want tuples, $(x, y)$ such that $x \ne y$.

I would therefore like to know what a tuple $(x,x)$ for an element $x$ is called in accepted mathematical parlance.

I will be calling it `<adjective>Pair` in my code, but I cannot found the right adjective online.  The best I can do is invent my own: `IdentityPair`, because an identity function $f$, when viewed as a relation over $S$, consists of pairs $(x,x)$ for all $x \in S$.

**EDIT:** Thanks to the commenters, I have the following adjectives to choose from:

- diagonal
- reflexive
- identity

Comment: At least in topology, the set $\{(x, x):\, x\in X\}$ is called the 'diagonal' of $X$. Pairs $(x, y)$ with $x\not= y$ could presumably be termed non-diagonal elements.

Comment: Reflexive pair?  When referring to relations (which are subsets of cartesian products), we call the relation reflexive if $(x,x)\in R$ for all $x$ in the set.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific terminology for the entity you mention. There are, however, several "indirect" ways to refer such ordered pairs. I suggest you name it yourself.

Comment: What would you call it Git?

Comment: @TahirHassan A Gud Pair. Or the identity function whose domain is $S\cap T$, I don't know...

Comment: For the sake of completeness, $(x, x)$ is referred to a "loop" in graph theory.

Comment: Perhaps `SquarePair`, partly because it's the only element of the Cartesian square of $\{x\}$ and partly because it rhymes

Comment: Maybe `constant pair`.

Comment: The adjective *diagonal* is also used [in category theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diagonal+morphism) for basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to generalize to three elements $(x,y,z)$. In particular, call $(x,x)$ a foo pair, and $(x,y)$ with $x \neq y$ a non-foo pair. Question: is $(x,x,y)$ with $x \neq y$ a foo pair? If not, foo = "constant sequence." If so, foo = "non-injective sequence."